# Aws billing pricing shutting down server

Tags: amazon-ec2, price

I have a client aws account i cannot get access to and he cannot access gmail to change password. He owns an ec2 instance. I have ssh access. If i go in and shut down the server, not able to terminate,  what will my monthly charges be. We have the 30g storage im sure is ebs. Owner says its either micro or medium i assume I can figure that out myself with free command

Comment: What's wrong with the question why am i getting negative votes?

Comment: Should it be on a different stack site

Comment: The owner of the account should contact AWS Support. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly - if neither of you have access to the account, who does? As suggested in the comments you should contact AWS support to gain access to the account based on your account information.

Secondly, to your question, if the only thing running on the account is one instance with attached EBS that doesn't get any traffic, no snapshots, and no other services deployed, you would only pay for the EBS volume.

Please note that if you have programmatic access with the right privileges you can use the AWS CLI (or SDK) to terminate the instance and the EBS:

```
  terminate-instances
  --instance-ids <value>
  [--dry-run | --no-dry-run]
  [--cli-input-json <value>]
  [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html